# sharepoint workflow rest api add role assignment exception

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, rest, roles

I develop a workflow and i want to grant unique permission on item in list using sharepoint rest api

```
http://sp_site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items(1)/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true, clearSubscopes=true)
```

then

```
http://sp_site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items(1)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=20,roleDefId=1073741828)
```

the rest service return exception

> Value does not fall within the expected range

please advice

Comment: i see their is no single quotes in the Items(1)...could you please put that and try again

Comment: Guess you would get another exception, but did you use `POST`verb?